# SQL query to search for hotel availability

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables with following columns:

> hotel (id, name, address)
>
> room (id, name, price, hotel_id)
>
> room_calendar (customer_id, room_id, date) we will create a date record for the specific room if it is booked by the specific customer.

How can I query the database directly based on arrival date and departure date to check for hotel availability?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve your problem? Please show us your approach. Mention: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Sorry. I am a new comer here.  I am not sure how could I get some help from the community.

Comment: See Esteban's suggestions. You might also take a look at [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN on room_calendar table with your searching date.

Keep an eye on: `WHERE room_calendar.date IS NULL`
If there is no row for this room in room_calendar table, the room is not booked for this day.

```
    SELECT hotel.name
          ,room.name
          ,room.price
      FROM hotel
INNER JOIN room
        ON room.hotel_id = hotel.id
 LEFT JOIN room_calendar
        ON room_calendar.room_id = room.id
       AND room_calendar.date = @yourdate
     WHERE room_calendar.date IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to create a view for further query? For example, each record represent that hotel is full (all rooms are booked) on specific date.